# Is there a cleaner way to pass kwargs from class to a function

Tags: python, python-class

I'm just getting started with kwargs in python classes, and I'm confident this is a trivial question, but I cannot find a sufficient answer online.

I have a class that with config values that are used in many functions, however there are
some calls where the value has to be overruled

Here is a simplified version of my problem with the context of verbosity:

My requirements are:

1. verbose becomes the config value if not declared otherwise

```
test().func() -> "Verbose = True"
```

2. verbose becomes the kwarg passed to the class upon init.

```
test(verbose=False).func() -> "Verbose = False"
```

3. verbose becomes the kwarg passed to the function upon func call.

```
test().func(verbose=False) -> "Verbose = False"
```

4. (optionally but not necessary at the sacrifice of even an extra line of complexity):
   verbose becomes config even without init

```
test.func() -> "Verbose = True"
```

My Solution:

```
class test():

    CONFIG = {"verbose":True}

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(self.CONFIG)
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
    
        
    def func(self=None,**kwargs):
        verbose = kwargs['verbose'] if 'verbose' in kwargs else self.verbose
        print(f"Verbose = {verbose}")
```

My Problem:
This doesn't seem like the *right* way to tackle the problem. This seems like a convoluted way to handle this, and it feels like there is a built-in or standard solution I'm missing. An even bigger issue is that I don't like that I have to make a line like this for every variable and in every function that I want to treat like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` method with a default.

```
def funct(self, **kwargs):
    verbose = kwargs.get('verbose', self.verbose)
    print(f"Verbose = {verbose}")
```

BTW, there's no need for a default for `self`, since this argument is always passed automatically to methods.

Comment: Thanks. When you mean no need for a default for self, are you referring to self=None? I often write my methods in a way where I can call them without initiating the class(for use in similar projects). This way when defining def method1(self=None,arg1):, you can call it with class1.method1(arg1). I have never seen this anywhere other than my own code. do you think it is impractical or wrong?

Comment: Yes,that's what I was referring to. I also haven't seen that pattern. If the method doesn't need a `self` argument, it should be defined as `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
class test():
    # A class variable will act as a default value for objects.
    verbose = True

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        # It's better to use setattr. Modifying __dict__ might bypass some
        # important automated stuff.
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
    
    # self must not be None. 'None.verbose' is an error.
    def func(self, **kwargs):
        # Use the get method when the value might not be in the dict.
        verbose = kwargs.get('verbose', self.verbose)
        print(f"Verbose = {verbose}")
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well, this is exactly what I was looking for.